# ConcurrentDictionary cast to IDictionary, indexer for missing key no longer throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, exception

I found some surprising behavior today when doing some unit tests. If you cast a .NET `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>` instance (have not tested with the standard generic `Dictionary<K, V>`) to an `IDictionary`, and then use the indexer, it no longer throws a missing key exception:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NotInDictionaryNative()
{
    var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
    dict["abc"] = 3;
    dict["def"] = 4;

    Assert.IsTrue( ( (IDictionary)dict )["q"] == null );
}
```

This unit test passes! However if you take out the cast, it fails. This seems to be dangerous behavior: an explicit implementation should not vary so much from the regular public indexer, should it?

So, if the only known type that I have is `IDictionary`, how can I check for the existence of a key short of looping through all the keys and comparing?

Comment: That is the expected behaviour of `IDictionary.Item` - see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have I missed something, or is there a reason you can't use [IDictionary.ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @JohnH, unfortunately there is no such method defined on `IDictionary`. The `Contains(object key)` method checks whether the given value exists rather than the key.

Comment: @BrucePierson you are *not* using the expected `IDictionary<T,V>` interface but the very old `IDictionary` that returns objects. That's a very unusual cast

Comment: The [IDictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h(v=vs.110).aspx) interface *does* throw an exception. The far older (.NET 1.0) IDictionary doesn't. Just don't use `IDictionary`

Comment: @BrucePierson [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)  *does* offer methods to check for existence, even atomic GetOrAdd, AddOUpdate functionality, etc. It's all in the docs. `ContainsKey` *is* available through the `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` interface but the other methods are preferable when the dictionary may be modified by other threads

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, can you recommend a cast syntax for `IDictionary<K, V>` from an `object` when I need to check its type for any key and value type? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @BrucePierson check the docs. It's all there. In the thread-safe section there is [How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows how to add/update/read items properly

Comment: @BrucePierson emphasis on *thread-safe*. You *can't* check for existence before reading or setting because another thread may modify the dictionary at the same time. You need to use one of the atomic operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am very well versed in `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>`. My question has more to do with what I see as varying behavior for the indexer when casting an instance.

Comment: @BrucePierson because you used an obsolete interface that demands that `Item` doesn't throw. Just don't use it. It's there only for compatibility with older, non-generic code.You can use `ContainsKey`, but it's not thread-safe.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm going to move this to chat so that I can give more background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143521/discussion-between-bruce-pierson-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item(v=vs.110).aspx :

> The element with the specified key, or null if the key does not exist.

So this is expected behaviour.

> This seems to be dangerous behavior: an explicit implementation should not vary so much from the regular public indexer, should it?

It darn well should when its documented as doing so, unless there's a **very** good reason not to (enough really for the documentation to be considered buggy).

> So, if the only known type that I have is IDictionary, how can I check for the existence of a key short of looping through all the keys and comparing?

`IDictionary.Contains` though this is a nuisance (and a race in multi-threaded scenarios), which is why `KeyNotFoundException` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue` were introduced with 2.0.

The lack of a `TryGetValue` method meant that in 1.1 the only way to have a test on an `IDictionary` for a key that may not be present without throwing was to know that `null` was never going to be added in there. This is far from ideal, so the generic equivalent changed that, but its too late to update `IDictionary` to match as all existing uses would be broken.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I see by looking at the contract the words "null if the key does not exist". So MS I guess had no choice but to provide varying implementations of the indexer for the explicit implementation. I've solved my problem with `( (dynamic)rhs ).ContainsKey( lhs )`.

Comment: `IDictionary.Contains` should work as well, and without having the overhead of going through `dynamic`. Either way has a race condition if another thread could update it between the contain check and an action on based on the result.

Comment: Of course you are right. Thanks. It's been a long week. I guess just as the new indexer behavior is preferred over the old, `ContainsKey` is preferred over `Contains`, and I read the old `Contains` method as checking for the existence of values rather than keys. My mistake, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are contracts, those contracts can include what exceptions a member will or will not threw. The [IDictionary.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item(v=vs.110).aspx) contract does not say that implementers will be throwing a keynotfound exception so the implementers should not throw it.